# Django wizard forms and dynamic formset creation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Usually, in a wizard, we declare forms or formsets in static way, for example with something like:

```
form_class=formset_factory(MyForm, min_num=1, extra=5)  # let's say this is step '4'
```

But now, what if I need data from step 3, to know how to define the `min_num` or `extra` value for the formset of step 4?

I was thinking of doing such thing in the `get_form()` method:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super().get_form(step, data, files)

    # ....

    elif step == '4':
        step3_data = self.storage.get_step_data('3')

        # ... here I would parse step 3 data, to be able to define:
        computed_step_4_min_num = 5
        computed_step_4_extra = 10

        # And here I would need to call formset_factory(min_num=computed_step_4_min_num,
                                                        extra=computed_step_4_extra),
        # but how? This is obviously not the right place for this call.
```

While it's easy to edit form fields attributes in the `get_form()` method, I did not find a way to define the right number of forms of a formset, in a dynamic way.

I read documentation but I could have missed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [documentation](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) and [checking the source code](https://github.com/jazzband/django-formtools/blob/af200c06c224c2dcb16857203bcdf2c264d4a5b0/formtools/wizard/views.py#L398), I think this is the optimal solution to use:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    if step == '4':
        step3_data = self.storage.get_step_data('3')
        # do calculations
        computed_step_4_min_num = 5
        computed_step_4_extra = 10
        form = formset_factory(MyForm, min_num=computed_step_4_min_num, extra=computed_step_4_extra)
        self.form_list[step] = form
    return super().get_form(step, data, files)
```

I am overriding the `self.form_list` to add the formset factory. But you should add a formset in the view when initiating the Wizard instance:

```
>> formset = formset_factory(MyForm, min_num=1, extra=1)
>> MyWizardForm.as_view([Form1, Form2, Form3, formset], initial_dict=initial)
```